# GitHub Actions: How to run jobs in a container

Tags: github-actions

I try to transfer my projects CI to GitHub Actions. For integration tests I need to start and access redis container. I am using info from this
[article](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/about-service-containers#communicating-with-service-containers).
So code looks like this

```
build-artifacts:
    name: Build artifacts
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      redis:
        image: redis:3.2.12
        ports:
        - 6379:6379
```

I can access redis using `localhost:6379` but I can't access it using `redis:6379`. The article does not help. What I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out what was the problem.
Docker network works only if you run your job inside container. And I had not.

Here is example https://github.com/actions/example-services/blob/989ef69ed164330bee413f11ce9332d76f943af7/.github/workflows/mongodb-service.yml#L19

And a quote:

> runs all of the steps inside the specified container rather than on the VM host.
> Because of this the network configuration changes from host based network to a container network.

Answer (score 0):

U need to host an external redis database because containers in GitHub Actions are isolated.
For other hand u can prepare a docker container with all you need for testing and then u can run the tests inside.

Un can take a look here https://github.com/gonsandia/github-action-deploy
Its a custom action where u define the dockerfile and the scripts to runs

Comment: I forget to mension I want to run this steps on github server by pushing code. I can not host external redis anywhere.

Comment: Then u have to prepare a dockerfile with redis setup and the other stuff u need to run tests. Here https://github.com/gonsandia/github-action-deploy  you can check an example for a custom dockerfile and scripts and how to call a custom action